# Verify umask value in UNIX terminal

Tags: unix

In my terminal I changed the bitmask to "umask 022" and was just wondering what command do you use to verify that the bitmask was changed?

Comment: What about a `touch testfile`?

Comment: Not sure what that does...

Answer (score 2):

Just run `umask` without an argument and it'll print the current umask of the shell process.

Comment: When I use the command "umask" it will go back to the default umask which is 0022.

Comment: @user3467039 No, it doesn't change the umask. Are you complaining about the extra leading zero? It doesn't mean anything.